# How to generate a window around a variable with multiple events per Symbol?

Tags: r, events, window

I have a problem..My panel dataset looks like this data without the variable “Window”. Now I am trying to create the variable “Window” look like this:

```
Symbol  Date        Close       Time      Event  Window
AAPL    09/03/2020  66,542503   16:25:00    NA    NA
AAPL    09/03/2020  71,334999   16:26:00    NA    -4
AAPL    09/03/2020  68,857498   16:27:00    NA    -3
AAPL    09/03/2020  62,057499   16:28:00    NA    -2
AAPL    09/03/2020  69,4925     16:29:00    NA    -1
AAPL    09/03/2020  60,552502   16:30:00    1      0
AAPL    09/03/2020  63,215      16:31:00    NA     1 
AAPL    10/03/2020  61,6675     09:30:00    NA     2 
AAPL    10/03/2020  61,195      09:31:00    NA     3 
AAPL    10/03/2020  57,310001   09:32:00    NA     4  
AAPL    10/03/2020  56,092499   09:33:00    NA    NA 
AAPL    15/03/2020  65,535603   15:45:00    NA    NA
AAPL    15/03/2020  66,357545   15:46:00    NA    NA
AAPL    15/03/2020  62,852345   15:47:00    NA    -4
AAPL    15/03/2020  64,057325   15:48:00    NA    -3
AAPL    16/03/2020  66,494545   09:30:00    NA    -2
AAPL    16/03/2020  63,557967   09:31:00    1     -1
AAPL    16/03/2020  64,415454   09:32:00    NA     0 
AAPL    16/03/2020  62,2357     09:33:00    NA     1 
AAPL    16/03/2020  64,4576     09:34:00    NA     2 
AAPL    16/03/2020  59,457579   09:35:00    NA     3  
AAPL    16/03/2020  58,092470   09:36:00    NA     4 
VISA    05/03/2020  186,960007  16:26:00    NA    NA 
VISA    05/03/2020  184,360001  16:27:00    NA    -4 
VISA    05/03/2020  171,130005  16:28:00    NA    -3 
VISA    05/03/2020  182,600006  16:29:00    NA    -2 
VISA    05/03/2020  172,949997  16:30:00    NA    -1 
VISA    06/03/2020  160,080002  09:32:00    1      0
VISA    06/03/2020  175,830002  09:33:00    NA     1 
VISA    06/03/2020  152,009995  09:34:00    NA     2 
VISA    06/03/2020  157,889999  09:35:00    NA     3 
VISA    06/03/2020  148,479996  09:36:00    NA     4 
VISA    06/03/2020  152,25      09:37:00    NA    NA 
VISA    06/03/2020  146,830002  09:38:00    NA    NA 
VISA    20/03/2020  192,203826  16:12:00    NA    NA 
VISA    20/03/2020  193,293752  16:13:00    NA    -4 
VISA    20/03/2020  192,204726  16:14:00    NA    -3 
VISA    20/03/2020  192,2396    16:15:00    NA    -2 
VISA    20/03/2020  194,185620  16:16:00    NA    -1 
VISA    20/03/2020  196,614289  16:17:00    1      0
VISA    20/03/2020  197,826200  16:18:00    NA     1 
VISA    21/03/2020  197,49176   09:29:00    NA     2 
VISA    21/03/2020  197,239230  09:30:00    NA     3 
VISA    21/03/2020  198,2300    09:31:00    NA     4 
VISA    21/03/2020  198,230028  09:32:00    NA    NA 
VISA    21/03/2020  197,247020  09:33:00    NA    NA
```

I have already tried the following code I have found:

> EventStudy <- EventStudy %>%   group_by(Symbol) %>%     mutate(Window =
> row_number() - match(1, Event), Window = ifelse(abs(Window) > 4, NA, Window))
> %>%     ungroup

Unfortunately, it only gives me one Window per symbol, but I have multiple events per symbol in my code. So for example, for the Symbol "AAPL" I have two Events.

I also tried to use the code without group_by, but it doesn't work as intended either. I also don't have a suitable grouping for the dataset, after which I only have one event per group.

Is there any way to modify the code, for multiple events for one symbol? Can you please help me to create the variable "Window"?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include some test data that can be directly pasted to R next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of a helper function to get the closest index of `Event = 1` value.

```
library(dplyr)

closest_index <- function(x, y) {
  y <- which(y == 1)
  y[sapply(x, function(i) which(abs(y - i) == min(abs(y - i)))[1])]
}

EventStudy %>%
  group_by(Symbol) %>%
  mutate(close_index = closest_index(row_number(), Event),  
         Window = row_number() - close_index, 
         Window = ifelse(abs(Window) > 4, NA, Window)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-close_index)
```

This returns -

```
#   Symbol       Date      Close     Time Event Window
#1    AAPL 09/03/2020  66,542503 16:25:00    NA     NA
#2    AAPL 09/03/2020  71,334999 16:26:00    NA     -4
#3    AAPL 09/03/2020  68,857498 16:27:00    NA     -3
#4    AAPL 09/03/2020  62,057499 16:28:00    NA     -2
#5    AAPL 09/03/2020    69,4925 16:29:00    NA     -1
#6    AAPL 09/03/2020  60,552502 16:30:00     1      0
#7    AAPL 09/03/2020     63,215 16:31:00    NA      1
#8    AAPL 10/03/2020    61,6675 09:30:00    NA      2
#9    AAPL 10/03/2020     61,195 09:31:00    NA      3
#10   AAPL 10/03/2020  57,310001 09:32:00    NA      4
#11   AAPL 10/03/2020  56,092499 09:33:00    NA     NA
#12   AAPL 15/03/2020  65,535603 15:45:00    NA     NA
#13   AAPL 15/03/2020  66,357545 15:46:00    NA     -4
#14   AAPL 15/03/2020  62,852345 15:47:00    NA     -3
#15   AAPL 15/03/2020  64,057325 15:48:00    NA     -2
#16   AAPL 16/03/2020  66,494545 09:30:00    NA     -1
#17   AAPL 16/03/2020  63,557967 09:31:00     1      0
#18   AAPL 16/03/2020  64,415454 09:32:00    NA      1
#19   AAPL 16/03/2020    62,2357 09:33:00    NA      2
#20   AAPL 16/03/2020    64,4576 09:34:00    NA      3
#21   AAPL 16/03/2020  59,457579 09:35:00    NA      4
#22   AAPL 16/03/2020  58,092470 09:36:00    NA     NA
#23   VISA 05/03/2020 186,960007 16:26:00    NA     NA
#24   VISA 05/03/2020 184,360001 16:27:00    NA     -4
#25   VISA 05/03/2020 171,130005 16:28:00    NA     -3
#26   VISA 05/03/2020 182,600006 16:29:00    NA     -2
#27   VISA 05/03/2020 172,949997 16:30:00    NA     -1
#28   VISA 06/03/2020 160,080002 09:32:00     1      0
#29   VISA 06/03/2020 175,830002 09:33:00    NA      1
#30   VISA 06/03/2020 152,009995 09:34:00    NA      2
#31   VISA 06/03/2020 157,889999 09:35:00    NA      3
#32   VISA 06/03/2020 148,479996 09:36:00    NA      4
#33   VISA 06/03/2020     152,25 09:37:00    NA     NA
#34   VISA 06/03/2020 146,830002 09:38:00    NA     NA
#35   VISA 20/03/2020 192,203826 16:12:00    NA     NA
#36   VISA 20/03/2020 193,293752 16:13:00    NA     -4
#37   VISA 20/03/2020 192,204726 16:14:00    NA     -3
#38   VISA 20/03/2020   192,2396 16:15:00    NA     -2
#39   VISA 20/03/2020 194,185620 16:16:00    NA     -1
#40   VISA 20/03/2020 196,614289 16:17:00     1      0
#41   VISA 20/03/2020 197,826200 16:18:00    NA      1
#42   VISA 21/03/2020  197,49176 09:29:00    NA      2
#43   VISA 21/03/2020 197,239230 09:30:00    NA      3
#44   VISA 21/03/2020   198,2300 09:31:00    NA      4
#45   VISA 21/03/2020 198,230028 09:32:00    NA     NA
#46   VISA 21/03/2020 197,247020 09:33:00    NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases where I wouldn't use tidyverse style. I would go for a small `for` loop over the lags (only 9 iterations):

```
## test data
event <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1 , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1 , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1 , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)


event_pos <- which(event == 1)
window <- rep(NA, length(event))

for (dif in -4:4) {
  window[event_pos+dif] <- dif 
}
```

Note that this code does not handle special cases like overlapping windows or lags that leave the range of the data. But it could easily be adapted to handle such situations.

Result:

```
     event window
        NA     NA
        NA     -4
        NA     -3
        NA     -2
        NA     -1
         1      0
        NA      1
        NA      2
        NA      3
        NA      4
        NA     NA
        NA     NA
        NA     -4
        NA     -3
        NA     -2
        NA     -1
         1      0
        NA      1
        NA      2
        NA      3
        NA      4
        NA     NA
        NA     NA
        NA     -4
        NA     -3
        NA     -2
        NA     -1
         1      0
        NA      1
        NA      2
        NA      3
        NA      4
        NA     NA
```

You can easily adapt the code to work on the groups of symbols and to handle edge cases:

```
library(tidyverse)


create_window <- function(event) {
  
  event_pos <- which(event == 1)
  
  if (length(event_pos) == 0) {
    return(rep(NA, length(event)))
  }
  
  window <- rep(NA, length(event) + 8) ## add 8 for edge cases
  
  for (dif in -4:4) {
    window[event_pos+dif+4] <- dif 
  }
  
  ## remove superfluous 8
  window <- window[-c(1:4, (length(window):(length(window)-3)))]
  
  window
  
}

testdata %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  mutate(window = create_window(event)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Some timings for 200 million rows of 100k symbols and 1.5 million events on my machine with 16GB RAM and i5-6600K: It takes ~7.2s

```
testdata <-
  tibble(event = rep(NA_real_, 200000000),
         symbol = rep(1:100000, c(rmultinom(1, 200000000, rep(1/100000, 100000)))))

testdata$event[sample.int(length(testdata$event)-9, 1500000)+4] <- 1

microbenchmark::microbenchmark({
  
  testdata %>% 
    group_by(symbol) %>% 
    mutate(window = create_window(event)) %>% 
    ungroup()

  
},
times = 10)

###
##     mean   median       uq      max neval
## 7.650121 7.201488 7.390293 10.21066    10
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! I should have added in the text that my dataset contains millions of observations, so it is not so easy for me to use a vector here. But thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The solution you accepted uses (many!) additional vectors of the same length as the data, needs more memory and is certainly slower than this. Just because the for-loop is hidden in a pipe and in `sapply` it does not get magically more efficient. I have edited my answer to show some timings. But whatever works for you ;)

Comment: Thank you! It works very good! Can you still help me to stop the event window when a new company starts its observations, so that no observations from the next or previous company are included in the event window?

Comment: I fully agree that speed is the least important aspect here. I just added the timings because OPs comment seemed to indicate that he thought this answer was not fast enough.
Also, nothing in the question actually said that the grouping is necessary or how edge cases (window at the start/end; not enough observations; etc) should be handled. 
In any case, I added a version that handles groups of symbols and edge cases. It is still fast. I tried to additionally time the other solution, but stopped it after ~60s (for one run) when it was still not finished.